# Query to generate each row using startdate and enddate from the history table

Tags: sql-server-2014

I have a history table like below:

```
Custid, custname, salary, startdate, enddate
1,aaa,5000,01-01-2018,31-03-2019
1,bbb,4000,01-01-2018,31-03-2019
1,aaa,6000,01-04-2019,24-07-2019
```

I need to generate a row from startdate (01-01-2018) to enddate (31-03-2019) for each day. Custid, custname and salary same for each row till end date. Please find the below data as example.

```
Custid, custname, salary, Effective date
1,aaa,5000,01-01-2018
1,aaa,5000,02-01-2018
1,aaa,5000,03-01-2018
,,,,,
1,aaa,5000,31-03-2019  (salary 5000 till 31-03-2019)
1,aaa,6000,01-04-2019  (salary 6000 from here)
1,aaa,6000,02-04-2019
,,,,,
1,aaa,6000,24-07-2019
```

Please provide some suggestions on this query.

Answer (score 1):

Given this sample data*:

```
CREATE TABLE #foo(Custid int, custname sysname, salary int, startdate date, enddate date);

INSERT #foo (Custid, custname, salary, startdate, enddate) VALUES
(1,N'aaa',5000,'20180101','20190331'),
(1,N'bbb',4000,'20180101','20190331'),
(1,N'aaa',6000,'20190401','20190724');
```

You can use a CTE that generates the list of potential dates, and then join against it based on the start/end dates:

```
DECLARE @min date, @max date;    
SELECT @min = MIN(startdate), @max = MAX(enddate) FROM #foo;

;WITH dates AS 
(
  SELECT day = @min UNION ALL 
  SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,day) FROM dates WHERE day < @max
)
SELECT f.Custid, f.custname, f.salary, dates.day
  FROM dates INNER JOIN #foo AS f
  ON dates.day >= f.startdate AND dates.day <= f.enddate
  ORDER BY f.Custid, f.custname, dates.day
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

> *`*` Please use unambiguous and universal date formats, like `YYYYMMDD`. I spent 5 minutes troubleshooting why the salary changed on January 4th instead of April 1st.*

Comment: Thank you so much Aaron, will check it and get back if any issues.